# 2 oppositely charged spheres are attracted to each other, and one of them is touched to an earth wire, what is the resulting charge?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

So a negatively charged sphere and a sphere S which has been attracted to it(the electrons have been repelled to the right, and the positive charges are in its left side).  They are now "stuck" to each other and are touching. An earth wire is touched to S. I understand that the negative charges in the right side of S will flow into the Earth, and S will be left with a positive charge. But won't there be a certain point where all the negative charges in S have already left it and the wire is still connected? What happens then? Will negative charges flow back up to neutralize the positively charged S?

Comment: Attached, as in connected by a wire ? Or just physically close ?

Comment: I mean that because they have unlike charges, S has now become attracted to and "stuck" to the sphere. They are touching.

Comment: Can you explain why you think the negative charge might leave $S$ and eventually come back? What would cause that to happen?

Comment: @KitKat If the two spheres come in physical contact, the net charge will get distributed amongst themselves according to their capacitance. If they are identical, the net charge gets distributed equally. The magnitude of charges on both the spheres and their dimensions are required to be able to say what exactly would happen when one is grounded.